# why does do.call function make a mistake in this case?

Tags: r

In the book Machine learning for Hackers, this is a case in Chapter 1, and a line of code like this:

```
city.state<-lapply(ufo$Location,get.location)
head(city.state)
location.matrix<-do.call(rbind,city.state)
ufo<-transform(ufo,USCity=location.matrix[,1],USState=location.matrix[,2],
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Problem was, when I run the code it shows me:

```
> Error in data.frame(list(DateOccured = c(9412, 9413, 9131, 9260,
> 9292,  :    参数值意味着不同的行数: 61139, 61138
```

And it shows in the global environment that city.state is a list of 61139 elements which equals to the ufo data, whereas location.matrix turn out to be a matrix of 61138 rows after do.call function was ran. What confused me most is how on earth is there a row missing by do.call function?

What is happening here?Can anyone tell me?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was that you had missed a few lines from [this script](https://github.com/mythicalprogrammer/ML-for-hackers/blob/master/chp1/ufo_sightings.R) that remove invalid dates:

```
good.rows<-ifelse(nchar(ufo$DateOccurred)!=8 | nchar(ufo$DateReported)!=8,FALSE,TRUE)
ufo<-ufo[good.rows,]
ufo$DateOccurred<-as.Date(ufo$DateOccurred,"%Y%m%d")
ufo$DateReported<-as.Date(ufo$DateReported,"%Y%m%d")
```

I had not thought to translate your error message:

```
parameter value means different number of rows: 61139, 61138
```

I do not see this error with R-3.6. Did you run any other code that is not in the linked script?

Comment: Well actually I didn't missed these lines, and it shows in the global environment that city.state is a list of 61139 elements which equals to the ufo data, whereas location.matrix    turn out to be a matrix of 61138 rows after do.call function was ran. What confused me most is how on earth is there a row missing by do.call function?

Comment: @tour I checked out the project linked above, ran the script and could not recreate the error you are seeing.